# Where do wizards give birth?

Tags: harry-potter, wizards

When reading about St.Mungos I didn't see delivery room mentioned there. Do they go to Muggle hospitals? Do they deliver at home?

Comment: *Accio baby*! ;-)

Comment: Really?LOL, that would look interestingXD

Comment: Are we talking about male wizards, or female wizards?

Comment: St Mungos seems to be more of an Accident and Emergency department. They don't seem to deal with births and routine operations in the same way that Muggle hospitals do. I'm guessing that most people give birth at home.

Comment: A hos-spell-tal,  of course! *heh*

Comment: A few inches below the waist, I’d imagine.

Comment: I felt my answer to this one was pretty comprehensive given the canon source of information (written by JKR). Is there anything else you'd want to see before reconsidering your acceptance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's not any particular hospital mentioned in the book or movie.

However, in **Order of Phoenix**, there was a mention of *[Neonatal Intensive Care Unit](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Neonatal_Intensive_Care_Unit)* in newspaper. It was an article written by Tilly Monk's husband. She gave birth to twins, Jack and Tom, there.

Other pregnancy cases were of **Merope Gaunt**, **Lily Potter**, and **Nymphadora**. Merope gave birth to Tom Riddle at the orphanage whereas there is no mention of rest.

[Source](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Pregnancy)

Comment: In OotP, was that the book or the movie?

Comment: http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Neonatal_Intensive_Care_Unit

Comment: Those twins are muggles born to muggle parents.

Answer (score 7):

**Most likely they give birth at home.**

In the absence of black magic, any normal ailments that can beset a pregnant woman would be [trivially simple for a Wizard or Witch midwife to cure](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/108947/are-wizarding-births-as-painful-as-muggle-births-also-magical-caesarians-breac/108996#108996), so a hospital visit would be utterly unnecessary. We see at least one example of this on Pottermore. Neville Longbottom's mother was *attended* by a midwife.

> Thus, the very moment that Neville Longbottom was born, the Quill
> attempted to write his name and was refused by the Book, which snapped
> shut. **Even the midwife who attended Alice Longbottom had failed to
> notice that Neville managed to shift his blankets more snugly over
> himself moments after birth, assuming that his father had tucked the
> baby in more securely.** Neville’s family persistently missed faint
> signs of magic in him and not until he was eight years old did either
> his disappointed great aunts and uncles, or the old stickler of a
> Book, accept that he was truly a wizard, when he survived a fall that
> should have killed him.
>
> <sub><sup>[Pottemore - The Quill of Acceptance and The Book of Admittance By J.K. Rowling](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/the-quill-of-acceptance-and-the-book-of-admittance)</sup></sub>